# Python's 'in' operator equivalent to C#

Tags: c#, python, operators

With Python, I can use 'in' operator for set operation as follows :

```
x = ['a','b','c']
if 'a' in x:
  do something
```

What's the equivalent in C#?

Comment: Don't know the exact syntax off the top of my head, but I bet you can do that with LINQ.

Comment: That's not a set operation, because that is a list rather than a set

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Most collections declare a `Contains` method (e.g. through the `ICollection<T>` interface), but there's always the more general-purpose LINQ [**`Enumerable.Contains`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) method:

```
char[] x = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

if(x.Contains('a'))
{
   ...    
}
```

If you think that's the 'wrong way around', you could write an extension that rectifies things:

```
public static bool In<T>(this T item, IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
   if(sequence == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");

   return sequence.Contains(item);    
}
```

And use it as:

```
char[] x = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

if('a'.In(x))
{
   ...    
}
```

Comment: Or `ContainsKey` if `x` is a dictionary.

Comment: Why would `sequence == null` provoke an exception, should just return false

Comment: @David Heffernan: That's an option, but in .NET, a `null` reference of a container-type is normally used to signify the *absence* of the container itself rather than an *empty* container. If we assume that convention; it is indeed an error for the second argument to be null.

Comment: @Ani Fair enough, I know little of .net conventions. One wonders why you don't just let the code progress to `sequence.Contains` if `sequence == null` is not a valid input.

Comment: @David: Python's `in` operator throws an exception for a `None` sequence, so this is the expected behavior.

Comment: @Gabe @Ani OK, I stand corrected! I still don't like all these `throw` statements though!

Comment: @David: Strictly speaking, it isn't necessary here, we can get rid of it: `Contains` will throw it for us. Of course, it's best practice for methods to validate their own arguments etc etc.

Comment: @Ani So I have at least contributed something of value, albeit limited!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the extensionmethod In<T>. If someone is used to the namingconventions of a language, in this case Python, he shouldn't use those conventions in another language(C# in this case), but he should use the conventions of the second language, C#. A few reasons: not doing so would decelerate the learning process of C#, the conventions will become inconsistent when he becomes more acquinted with C# and its conventions, and when the code is maintained by multiple programmers, they might be thrown off course by the Python namingconventions. So just use x.Contains('a')

Comment: I agree with @JBSnorro.  I dislike the way this `In<T>` method reads.  It feels funny.

Answer (score 2):

To build on [Ani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009882/pythons-in-operator-equivalent-to-c/5009899#5009899)'s answer, Python's `in` operator for dictionaries is the equivalent of `ContainsKey` in C#, so you would need two extension methods:

```
public static bool In<T, V>(this T item, IDictionary<T, V> sequence)
{
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    return sequence.ContainsKey(item);
}

public static bool In<T>(this T item, IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    return sequence.Contains(item);
}
```